# What are the perf implications of indexing a datetime column?

Tags: database, performance, database-design, indexing, database-performance

I realize that the answer here is probably some form of "it depends"; but I'm still wondering what (if any) the general rule of thumb is here.

If I want to enable "soft-deleting" records of a certain type, I might add a `deleted` column so I can do something like this (providing a Rails example, but I don't mean for the question to be Rails-specific):

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(:deleted => false) }
end
```

In this case I would imagine that indexing the `deleted` column would be relatively cheap as there are only two possible values: `true` or `false`.

Of course it might be useful to know *when* a record was deleted; so I could go with `deleted_at` instead:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(:deleted_at => nil) }
end
```

I've definitely seen this sort of thing quite a bit in the wild. My question is whether the indexing is actually much more expensive in this case, since basically every record will have a different value for `deleted_at`*. I know almost zero about database internals (something I definitely would like to read up on some day); so I recognize that this is probably a naive question.

And I know it probably depends on the database as well; if it matters, I'm mostly concerned with PostgreSQL. But I would imagine there are others who would also like to know about MySQL, Oracle, etc.

So? Little help?

<sup>* As I typed that sentence I *think* I realized the answer, since obviously every record has a different value for `id` as well but you don't think twice about indexing that. So probably date/time values work the same way? Anyway, I'd prefer an answer from someone with real knowledge on the subject rather than my hunch :)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The high over view of [**How database index works** could be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work).
Generally When designing indexes,

- Tree-based indexing(default strategy) is used to high-cardinality columns when values of the column repeats rarely AKA forgien key columns.
- [Bitmap indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index) have traditionally been considered to work well
  for low-cardinality columns when values of the column repeats very frequently like `deleted` field in the question, or the classical sample of `gender` filed that contains two distinct values: male or female.

One advantage of bitmap indexes is that a number of them can be ANDed and ORed together to answer queries very efficiently.
The [Working of indexes in postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql) and [some guidance on index strategies](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/where-can-i-find-some-guidance-on-index-strategies), may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the index is mainly influenced by two things:

1. The index key length (The number of bytes the each key value occupies).
2. The number of index rows (obviously)

Besides that, there is a overhead involved which you can generally not influence (e.g., the B-tree itself, references to the primary table store).

Answering your question: yes, a binary index might be smaller and faster, but not because of the number of distinct value, but just because one binary field needs less space than a date.

If you want to learn about SQL indexing, have a look at my site http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 1):

Indexing the deleted_at values would only be useful if you had a fairly frequent need to identify records that were deleted in a specific time range. If you do not need that ability -- if you just wanted to know when records identified by some other means were deleted, for example -- then it would not be worth indexing.

Of course once a record is deleted you'd probably expect it to never be modified again, so you could in practice use updated_at as the deletion timestamp.

If you want to identify non-deleted records quickly then if your RDBMS supports it a partial index would be appropriate. Syntax varies by system, but in brief you'd be looking to include in your indexes only the rows for which deleted_at is not null (or is_deleted => false).